# React script is found but it won't render the simple hello world element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to react and i'm just testing out a simple render at the moment. I get no errors in the browser but nothing shows up on my screen that appears in my javascript react file.

**html**

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script  type="text/babel" src="reactfile.js"> testing</script>
    </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
<body id="root">
    <p>react test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**react javascript file**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Helloworld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Helloworld />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('root')` vs `<body id="app">`. You'll need to use the same id for both.

Comment: Wrong ID but you're also missing a _few_ important bits, take a look at https://dev.to/tmhao2005/how-to-test-jsx-directly-on-browsers-without-any-building-steps-2i94 (first Google search results, there are many more examples out there). Also note that this is good for a quick test but you should quickly move away from it

Comment: Hi Adriano, I had fixed the id but it wasn't reflected in what I had pasted. A few other issues came up and when I had googled them I realize without a direct react build I require babel and browserify, specifically cdn links in the head tags for as well for react cdn links. I ended up essentially doing what your link describes thank you.

I'm assuming if were to build an app, I would not be using advice found in the link but rather using the create-react-app build features i'm assuming?

Comment: @justaskin yes, there are really FEW cases where you might need to do it this way (and even then...I'd think hard to find ANY other solution). If you're learning then IMHO I'd first start WITHOUT Create React App. It's handy but the boilerplate is minimal and it's really helpful to know those few steps first-hand.

Answer (score 0):

What you tell react with this line, is that you will put some HTML code inside the element with id `root`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Helloworld />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

However, in your HTML code, there is not such an element. In order to make it work, just add this element (with the id `root`) to your page, like this:

```
<body id="app">
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Then, every code that your React code will produce will be put in this element.

Comment: You're right I made a mistake, I had fixed it originally but uploaded the one with the wrong id. it did not fix the error though. I fixed it now and will edit my post. Thank you though. I would upvote you if I could.

Comment: Oh I see! Could you then provide us a reproducible example, in https://codesandbox.io/ for instance? Because I can't help just with the code you provided

Comment: Hi TheTisiboth, I fixed the issue and aside from the wrong id, it required incorporating scripts from babel and react through cdn links. A user by the name of adrian linked something earlier mentioning that. Essentially my html was missing the script files in the head element mentioned here https://dev.to/tmhao2005/how-to-test-jsx-directly-on-browsers-without-any-building-steps-2i94

Appreciate your concern and help though.

Comment: Oh I see, glad that you fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Make div with id "root" and add script tag below it. JavaScript can't access the root div before parsing it which means JavaScript can't find the element which doesn't appear in DOM tree. So you should put it script code at the end of line in body tag.

```
<body id="app">
    <p>react test</p>
    <div id="root></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="reactfile.js"></script>
</body>
```